# How can I iterate over list items in Pandoc's lua-filter function?

Tags: lua, abstract-syntax-tree, pandoc

Pandoc's [lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) makes it really easy to iterate over a document and munge the document as you go. My problem is I can't figure out how to isolate list item elements. I can find *lists* and the block level things inside each list item, but I can't figure out a way to iterate over list items.

For example let's say I had the following Markdown document:

```
1.  One string

    Two string

2.  Three string

    Four string
```

Lets say I want to make the first line of each list item bold. I can easily change how the paragraphs are handled inside OrderedLists, say using this filter and `pandoc --lua-filter=myfilter.lua --to=markdown input.md`

```lua
local i
OrderedList = function (element)
  i = 0
  return pandoc.walk_block(element, {
      Para = function (element)
          i = i + 1
          if i == 1 then return pandoc.Para { pandoc.Strong(element.c) }
          else return element end
        end
    })
end
```

This will indeed change the first paragraph element to bold, but it only changes the first paragraph of the first list item because it's iterating across all paragraphs in all list items in the list, not on each list item, then on each paragraph.

```
1.  **One string**

    Two string

2.  Three string

    Four string
```

If I separate the two list items into two separate lists again  the first paragraph of the first item is caught, but I want to catch the first paragraph of every list item! I can't find anything in the documentation about iterating over list items. How is one supposed to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pandoc Lua filter docs have recently been updated with more info on the properties of each type. E.g., for `OrderedList` elements, the [docs](http://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#type-ref-OrderedList) *should* say (it currently says `items` instead of `content`, which is a bug):

> ### OrderedList
>
> An ordered list.
>
> - `content`: list items (List of Blocks)
> - `listAttributes`: list parameters (ListAttributes)
> - `start`: alias for listAttributes.start (integer)
> - `style`: alias for listAttributes.style (string)
> - `delimiter`: alias for listAttributes.delimiter (string)
> - `tag`, `t`: the literal OrderedList (string)

So the easiest way is to iterate over the content field and change items therein:

```
OrderedList = function (element)
  for i, item in ipairs(element.content) do
    local first = item[1]
    if first and first.t == 'Para' then
      element.content[i][1] = pandoc.Para{pandoc.Strong(first.content)}
    end
  end
  return element
end
```

Comment: Wow, you probably don't want to see the 50 iterations of code _I_ tried. Thanks this works as expected and makes sense. The documentation (besides the bug) is very confusing with it's `List` helper type and then lists that are not _those_ lists.

Comment: I know, sorry 'bout that. We fixed it in the current dev version, all lists will be of type `List`.

Comment: Step 1, google for something. Step 2, find an answer that looks promising, not exactly your current problem but close enough for some pointers. Step 3, read the comments just to check if there are any emendations. Step 4, wonder who that Caleb fellow is. Wait what? I asked this question? I have no memory...